# Issue while inserting multiple images using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to generate excel report from php,in which there are two images for each row. But the generated excel sheet show images only for the first row.
following is my used code

```
  $pixels = 120;
  $points = PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::pixelsToPoints($pixels);
  $wpixels = 95;
  $wpoints = PHPExcel_Shared_Drawing::pixelsToPoints($wpixels);

  while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($rsExport)) {
      @extract($data);
      $image_path = "../../../upload/jrf/".$img_upload;
      $sign_path  = "../../../upload/jrf/".$sign_upload;
     $activeSheet->setCellValue("A".$rowNum, $i);
     $activeSheet->setCellValue("B".$rowNum, $jrf_roll_no);
     $activeSheet->setCellValue("C".$rowNum, $name);

     $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
     $objDrawing->setPath($image_path);
     $objDrawing->setCoordinates('D'.$rowNum);
     $objDrawing->setResizeProportional(false);
     $objDrawing->setWidth($wpoints);   
    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($activeSheet);

     $activeSheet->getRowDimension($rowNum)->setRowHeight($points);
     $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('D'.$rowNum)->setAutoSize(true);

     $objDrawing1 = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $objDrawing1->setPath($sign_path);
    $objDrawing1->setCoordinates('E'.$rowNum);
    $objDrawing1->setResizeProportional(false);

    $objDrawing1->setWidthAndHeight($wpoints,$points);
    $objDrawing1->setWorksheet($activeSheet);

   $activeSheet->getColumnDimension('E'.$rowNum)->setAutoSize(true);
   $rowNum++;
   $i++;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that one image isn't overlaid over the second?

Comment: yes..because for the other row it show image with cross ( like path not found)

Comment: Are you trying to show the same two images for every row?

Comment: No..actually its report of the candidates apply for the exam..so in that candidate's photo and uploaded signature get fetched from database.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Mlr9EkJutobUx1aUlyd2hDV2c/view?usp=sharing   this the generated excel

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Mlr9EkJutoYTI1aWdkVlVneGc/view?usp=sharing  and sometimes it show same signature in second row.

Comment: If these are all different images, then they all need to be different `PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing` objects; you're using the same variables for the obejcts in each row, which will override the object instances from the previous row

Comment: As I am creating object in while loop its creating new object all the time.when I display the path for each object I come to know that for the second record there is no image and from there its get break and if I  remove that record now its displaying images properly.. Thank you Mark for the help :)